# How can find some pin point with regex

Tags: regex, xml

I am trying to analyze a string with regex (e.g. `20, 38,`, `20, 24 n2,`, `20, 28, 38,`, `851, 859 n3,`) in XML files.

Example text:

```
<p>Gilmer v Interstate/Johnson Lane Corp. (1991) 500 US 20, 38, 111 S Ct 1647:</p>
<p>Gilmer v Interstate/Johnson Lane Corp. (1991) 500 US 20, 24 n2, 111 S Ct 1647</p>
<p>Gilmer v Interstate/Johnson Lane Corp.</italic> (1991) 500 US 20, 28, 38, 111 S Ct 1647</p>
<p>International Bhd. of Elec. Workers v Hechler (1987) 481 US 851, 859 n3, 107 S Ct 2161:</p>
```

I want to modify the `(\([^()]*)|([0-9]+,)\s*[0-9]+,?\s*[0-9]+,` regex because I am replacing the text with `$1$2`.

(https://regex101.com/r/jWt2w1/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(\([^()]*)|([0-9]+,)\s*[0-9]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?,?\s*[0-9]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?,
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/jWt2w1/3)

The `(?:\s+[a-z]+)?` optionally matches one or more whitespace characters and one or more letters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you solve my one more problem in link (https://regex101.com/r/jWt2w1/5). I want to search numeric value end with out comma. Please suggest.

Comment: @Sandy Sorry, I don't get this new requirement.  If `,` is optional add `?` after it